# How to access domain with www

Tags: domain-name, wildcard-subdomain, domainservices

I am facing  problem www URL I can't access URL with www .I want to access URL with www my domain name is http://test.com but I need to access http://www.test.com

Comment: OT, but make sure www exists in DNS, and your webserver (Apache,IIS,Nginx,etc..) has config for it...

Answer (score 1):

Check your dns records. You have to add a "www" subdomain with either a "IN A" recird to the ip were test.com is served, or a "IN CNAME" to "test.com." (note that final dot, it's important! it means that it's a fully qualified domain name, not another subdomain of the main zone).

For example, if you want www.test.com to point to the same thing that test.com do, add (in bind syntax) the folowing line to your zone :

```
www IN CNAME test.com.
```

hope that helps.